# Call to undefined method App\User::gravatar()

Tags: database, laravel, view

```html
<!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="{{ url('/home') }}" class="brand-link">
      <img src="{{ asset('/backend/dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png')}}" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
           style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">AdminLTE 3</span>
    </a>
    <?php $currentUser = Auth::user();?>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="{{ $currentUser->gravatar() }}" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="{{ $currentUser->name }}">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block">{{ $currentUser->name }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
 
      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i>
              <p>
                Dashboard
                <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="./index.html" class="nav-link active">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Dashboard v1</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="./index2.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Dashboard v2</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="./index3.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Dashboard v3</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="pages/widgets.html" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-th"></i>
              <p>
                Widgets
                <span class="right badge badge-danger">New</span>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
              <p>
                Charts
                <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/charts/chartjs.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>ChartJS</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/charts/flot.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Flot</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/charts/inline.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Inline</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-tree"></i>
              <p>
                UI Elements
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/UI/general.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>General</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/UI/icons.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Icons</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/UI/buttons.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Buttons</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/UI/sliders.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Sliders</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-edit"></i>
              <p>
                Blog
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>All Posts</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Add New</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-table"></i>
              <p>
                Tables
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/tables/simple.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Simple Tables</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/tables/data.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Data Tables</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-header">EXAMPLES</li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="pages/calendar.html" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>
              <p>
                Calendar
                <span class="badge badge-info right">2</span>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
              <p>
                Mailbox
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Inbox</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/mailbox/compose.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Compose</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/mailbox/read-mail.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Read</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
              <p>
                Pages
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/examples/invoice.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Invoice</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/examples/profile.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Profile</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/examples/login.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Login</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/examples/register.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Register</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/examples/lockscreen.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Lockscreen</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
              <p>
                Extras
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/examples/404.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Error 404</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/examples/500.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Error 500</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="pages/examples/blank.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Blank Page</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="starter.html" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Starter Page</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-header">MISCELLANEOUS</li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="https://adminlte.io/docs" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-file"></i>
              <p>Documentation</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-header">LABELS</li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o text-danger"></i>
              <p class="text">Important</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o text-warning"></i>
              <p>Warning</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-circle-o text-info"></i>
              <p>Informational</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method App\User::gravatar() (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\asset_manage\resources\views\layouts\backend\sidebar.blade.php) (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\asset_manage\resources\views\layouts\backend\sidebar.blade.php) (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\asset_manage\resources\views\layouts\backend\sidebar.blade.php)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzLjr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlkS6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrZji.png)

Comment: where is your User class?

Comment: maybe your gravatar() function don't exist

Comment: Please provide more info and some code as well.

Comment: look at the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the Gravatar value in the view parameter in your controller?

```
return view('YOUR_BLADE', ['gravatar' => $currentUser->gravatar()]);
```

Comment: what parts need to be replaced?

Comment: <img src="{{ gravatar }}" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="{{ $currentUser->name }}">

Comment: NOTE: Also you must set other variables you need alongside 'gravatar' into your controller! For example currentUser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column in users table named 'gravatar' then you can simply use in this way to get gravatar data of current user.

```
{{ Auth::user()->gravatar }}
```